# touch: cannot touch "test.list": Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am new in ubuntu 12.04 LTS .
I want to create list file in my etc/apt/sources.list.d/
folder but it writes that

```
touch: cannot touch `test.list': Permission denied
```

Comment: write su before to temporary get root permitions. # su command.

Comment: that's more of a superuser or askubuntu question, not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you don't have permissions to write in the folder. If you run `ls -l /etc/apt/` you'll see something like this.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-01-16 22:23 sources.list.d
```

Read `drwxr-xr-x` as 3 triples with a leading directory indicator `d rwx r-x r-x`.

- `d` just means it's a directory rather than a file.
- The first `rwx` indicated the permissions for the owner (later). in this casse all rights (`r`ead, `w`rite and e`x`ecute are granted)
- The second triplet `r-x` are the permissions for the group the directory belongs to. You see writing is prohibited.
- The last triplet tells you which permissions are set for everyone who's not the owner or in the group. Also you see writing is prohibited again.

So who is the owner and which groups is it associated to? You can get this from `root root` which is the owner and the group in the obvious form `owner group`.

So long to the backgrounds. For sure you could modify the right to allow writing for everybody on the system or change the group (and/or) owner to you but in general it's better to use put `sudo` as a prelude before your commands to gain `root` privileges for a short time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have root rights to do that. Try `sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/test.list`.